# Is it simple Math or something else?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, pattern, science

Grandpa with his mischievous smile said:

> "If zero belongs to One
>
> And two belongs to Four
>
> Twenty seven belongs to Seven
>
> Then what belongs to Three?"

Hint

> When I could not guess, I asked for a clue. He just smiled and said:
>
> "Think Son"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer is

> ONE

Explanation

> Counting from the centre of the solar system, One (the Mercury) has zero moons, Four (Mars) has two moons, Seven (Uranus) has 27 moons

And

> Three (Earth) has one moon

Hint:

> Son is a synonym of Sun

Comment: @DEEM edited thanks! nice riddle +1, but maybe the science and pattern tag instead of riddle?